# SQL loader POSITION giving errors

Tags: oracle

I have a question.I'd like to know how we can specify POSITION if we have a column that allows only 1 character? For ex: I have a table Example with column SEC (char (1).I am using control file to load it to my table.
My control file reads this:Note I am trying to insert SEC on position 2.

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'C:\Users\....\Data\h1.dat' 
BADFILE 'C:\Users\...\Reject\h1.bad' 
INSERT INTO TABLE EXAMPLE 
(SEC POSITION (2))
```

My log reads:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table SCHEDULE, column SEC.
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."EXAMPLE"."SEC")
```

Record 2:

```
Rejected - Error on table SCHEDULE, column SEC.
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."EXAMPLE"."SEC")
```

Comment: how can I make sure there are no blanks in data file?

Comment: Showing your data file, and possibly the table definition, might help.